# longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r

En la práctica me desaparecen las líneas que conectan los nodos al establecer el tamaño de ellos de forma que se vean de acuerdo a la cantidad que tienen y me aparece el siguiente error:

> Warning messages: 1: In layout[, 1] + label.dist * cos(-label.degree) * (vertex.size + : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Este es mi código:

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

datos <- read.csv(file = "c:/R/AEROLINEA.csv",header = TRUE, sep = ",")

valor1 = datos %>% group_by(ï..ORIGEN) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% arrange(-n)
valor1
valor2 = datos %>% group_by(DESTINO) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% arrange(-n)
valor2

datos1 = datos %>% summarise(valor1, valor2) %>% arrange(-n)
datos2 = datos1[1:10,]

g=graph.data.frame(datos2,directed = F)
plot.igraph(g,
edge.curved= F, #Artistas curvas F/T
edge.color = "black", #color de artistas
edge.width = 4, #ancho de artistas
edge.arrow.size =2,
vertex.label.color ="black",
vertex.label.cex = 0.8,
vertex.color="orange",
vertex.size = (datos2$n),
layout = layout.circle(g))
```

[image: asi resulta la imagen]